# Cannot install dependencies that requires VCBuild.exe

Tags: .net, node.js, visual-studio, npm

I am trying to install dependencies using `npm install` on a Windows 7 machine.  I got the following error message:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.
```

I installed .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, but the error continues, and indeed `VCBuild.exe` does not appear anywhere in the directory structure for .NET.

I don't have Visual Studio (of any vintage) on this machine, and I don't want to have to pay for it.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Old version of Visual C++ Express might have that, but VCBuild is dead and you should get rid of it and use MSBuild.

Comment: @LexLi I couldn't find MSBuild in my .NET framework installation either.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do all those things that error mentions? (1 and 2 / (or/and) 3)

> To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.

Comment: I read that as 1, 2 or 3.  What makes you think it is (1 and 2) or 3?